# How i can make flat button color look same like scaffold color background

Tags: flutter, dart

i have simple code right here:

```
LegacyFlatButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
  label: Text('Edit Location'),
  color: Colors.white,
),
```

I just want to remove the outline on this button, so that this button looks the same as the background color of the Scaffold.

[This My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20aLB.png)

Comment: Try setting the elevate property to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **TextButton.icon** widget try below code hope its help to you

```
TextButton.icon(
    onPressed: (){},
    icon: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
    label:Text('Edit Location'),
 )
```

Your result like -> [image]

Comment: I forgot i can use TextButton, Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @KisahTegarPutraAbdi Most Welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
LegacyFlatButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
  label: Text('Edit Location'),
  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
),
```

Simple